# Why the equation in Burnside's lemma has only one solution

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Burnside's lemma (for finite group) tells us that the square sum of dimensions over all inequivalent irreducible representations is equal to the order of the group, i.e.

$$
d_1^2 + d_2^2 + \cdots + d_r^2 = |G|
$$

where $d_i$ is the dimension of representation $D^{(i)}(g)$. It seems that for all finite groups, this equation has only one solution (for $d_i$). Is this true and how can I prove it or find a counter-example?

Comment: Sounds rather unlikely to me.

Comment: Even if you know  $r$ (and that is also not always the case) the $d_i$ are not uniquely determined. Thus, this equation is very helpful, but is not the final word on the $d_i$. (it so turns out that $d_i$ is a multiple of $|G|$ for each $i$, but even then uniqueness cannot be guaranteed).

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: Other way around: each $d_i$ divides $|G|$.

Comment: Yes, sorry : $d_i$ is a *divisor* of $|G|$. While this reduces the choices of $d_i$ greatly, it still  does not guarantee uniqueness, but makes the above equation supremely helpful.

Answer (score 6):

$$8 \times 1^2 + 2 \times 2^2 + 4^2 = 4\times 1^2 + 7 \times 2^2 = 32.$$
There are groups of order $32$ (numbers $6$ and $18$ in the database) with these character degrees.

Answer (score 3):

If a finite group $G$ has a representation with $d_i=2$ and $d_j=9$
then one can replace these by $6$ and $7$ without affecting the sum of the $d_i^2$s. So the equation $d_1^2 + d_2^2 + \cdots + d_r^2 = |G|$
may have multiple solutions in positive integers.

Comment: But does this actually correspond to some pair of non-isomorphic groups?

Comment: Probably not, but it makes the point that to determine the degrees of a groups characters, one has to do some group theory, Arithmetic is not sufficient... @TobiasKildetoft